# I am trying to count the number of occurrences of "pairs of word" in a text file using Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop

I am constanty getting this error of type Mismatch.

[image]

How do I solve this error? My Mapper output class is set to Text for key and `LongWritable` for Value. Also, I want to just calculate the number of times a pair of word appears in a text document and write it to the output file.

```
public class WordCountV2 extends Configured implements Tool {

        /** Entry-point for our program. Constructs a Job object representing a single
         * Map-Reduce job and asks Hadoop to run it.
         *
         */

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new WordCountV2(), args);
            System.exit(exitCode);
        }

        /**
         * Run method which schedules the Hadoop Job
         * @param args Arguments passed in main function
         */
        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

            if (args.length != 2) {
                System.err.printf("Usage: %s needs two arguments <input> <output> files\n", getClass().getSimpleName());
                return -1;
            }

        /*Initialize the Hadoop job and set the jar as well as the name of the Job
        * Tell Hadoop where to locate the code that must be shipped if this
        * job is to be run across a cluster.
        */
            Job job = new Job();
            job.setJarByClass(WordCountV2.class);
            job.setJobName("WordCounter");

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));


        /* Set the datatypes of the keys and values outputted by the maps and reduces.
         * These must agree with the types used by the Mapper and Reducer. Mismatches
         * will not be caught until runtime.
         *
         * job.setOutputKeyClass( Text.class ); will set the types expected as output from both the map and reduce phases.
         *
         * If your Mapper emits different types than the Reducer,
         * you can set the types emitted by the mapper with the JobConf's setMapOutputKeyClass() and setMapOutputValueClass() methods.
         * These implicitly set the input types expected by the Reducer.
         */

            //by default the output of mapper is KEY(Text) VALUE(Long)
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

            //Output file format is TextOutputFormat
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);


            //Set the MapClass and ReduceClass in the job
            job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
            job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);


            //Wait for the job to complete and print if the job was successful or not
            int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1;

            if(job.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Job was successful");
            } else if(!job.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Job was not successful");
            }

            return returnValue;
        }



        /** Mapper for word count. */

    public static class Map extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

        /** Regex pattern to find pairs of words (alphanumeric + _). */

        final static Pattern WORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(?=(\\s\\w+))");

        /** Constant 1 as a LongWritable value. */
        private final static LongWritable ONE = new LongWritable(1L);

        /** Text object to store a word to write to output. */
        private Text word = new Text();

        /** Actual map function. Takes one document's text and emits key-value
         * pairs for each word found in the document.
         *
         * @param key Document identifier (ignored).
         * @param value Text of the current document.
         * @param context MapperContext object for accessing output,
         *                configuration information, etc.
         */
        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            /* Matching the pattern with the input Text value*/

            Matcher matcher = WORD_PATTERN.matcher(value.toString());

            while (matcher.find()) {
                // group(1)--->Checks for words
                //group(2) ----> checks for spaces and words after
                word.set(matcher.group(1)+matcher.group(2));
                context.write(word, ONE);
            }
        }
    }

    /** Reducer for word count.
     *
     * Like the Mapper base class, the base class Reducer is parameterized by
     * <in key type, in value type, out key type, out value type>.
     *
     * For each Text key, which represents a pair of word, this reducer gets a list of
     * LongWritable values, computes the sum of those values, and the key-value
     * pair (word, sum).
     */
    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        /** Actual reduce function.
         *
         * @param key Word.
         * @param values Iterator over the values for this key.
         * @param context ReducerContext object for accessing output,
         *                configuration information, etc.
         */
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            long sum = 0L;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            context.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LongWritable instead of Text in map function

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
```

Comment: Doesn't the map function takes the key value pairs as the input we are passing to the Mapper? As the mapper accepts Object(Key), Text (Value), the map should have the Text,Text method ?

I may be wrong in understanding. Also changing the map function, still gives me an error.

Comment: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable